# Jquery Validation for Two Dropdown Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have Two dropdown boxes, if i select 4 from first select box, the value of the second dropdown value must be less than the first dropdown. if it fails show a custom error message, like that.

```
<select name="t_dropdown" id="t_dropdown" class="form-control required">
  <option value="">Select Value</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="p_dropdown" id="p_dropdown" class="form-control required">
  <option value="">Select Value</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value=">6">>6</option>
</select>
```

Please let me know, how to do it using jquery validations.

Comment: can u reproduce in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: my code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/76dvcaqz/

Comment: @user3264805 Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76dvcaqz/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.validator.addMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)-

```
$.validator.addMethod("matchValue", function (value, element) {
   if($('#t_dropdown').val()==4)
   {
       return value < 4;
   }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}, 'Invalid Value');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KrLkF/492/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KrLkF/493/